# How do I programmatically control the position of JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, viewport

I have a `JScrollPane` containing a `JPanel` and, in turn, a `JList`.  I want for the viewport to always show the *end* of the list (from which items are being removed or added).  I can accomplish this manually by dragging the `ScrollBar` to the bottom, where it stays, just the way I want it to.  What should I do to accomplish this automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be simple to do. Just use JList's `ensureIndexIsVisible` method and pass it the last index in the list (size - 1).

Comment: That does it, thanks: `myJList.ensureIndexIsVisible(myJList.getModel().getSize()-1);`

Answer (score -1):

You can use "scrollto" call while after creating JScrollPane.

here is the link for documentation. 
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/scroll_to.html

Comment: That's for jQuery, he's looking for the Java JScrollPane.

Comment: sorry my terrible mistake. i should've seen "tags" carefully. :)